# How to fix this error array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in

Tags: php, arrays, numeric

I have results like this in a nested array

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
         (
             [nisdt] => Error while providing NIS DT Contact the help team
             [nisn] => NISN must be at least 6 characters
         )

     [1] =>
)
```

Then I want to get array (not nested)

```
Array
(
     [0] => Error while providing NIS DT Contact the help team
     [1] => NISN must be at least 6 characters
)
```

> Warning: array_values () expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean
>   given in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ parenting \ index-2.php on line 71

How to resolve the error, this is my code.

```
function Return_Values($array) 
    { 
        return (array_values($array)); 
    }


    $return_val = Return_Values($tes_validation);
    foreach($return_val as $data)
    {
        $flip = Return_Values($data);
        print_r($flip);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, I think that this could helps with your problem.

```
foreach($tes_validation as $data)
{
    $flip = is_array($data) ? Return_Values($data) : $data;
    print_r($flip);
}
```